# Question about a Wheatstone bridge

Tags: bridge

Q) Suppose each bridge resistor is capable of dissipating 250mW. Can the bridge be left in the balanced state without exceeding the power-dissipating capacity of the resistors, thereby damaging the bridge?

A) yes

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhbNT2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I can't extremely understand why the answer is 'yes'.

Comment: Do you know what the resistance of R3 is when the bridge is in the balanced state?

Comment: @Dampmaskin Oh.. sorry I misdraw the circuit.... Ampere is 0A..

Comment: The values R1, R2, R3, R4 and I1 don't add up. At least one of them has to change.

Comment: The bridge you've drawn is not balanced and your "I1 0A" is not true. Your question can only be answered once you've corrected the circuit.

Comment: sorry... I've corrected my circuit..

Answer (score 1):

As Dampmaskin said, the schematic and values you have posted do not make a balanced bridge. So that makes it difficult to evaluate the circuit based on the premise of a "balanced state" of the question.

However, the only voltage source in the system, is V1 at 5V. We certainly can see how much power a resistor would consume in a worst-case condition of being placed directly across V1. Testing the smallest resistors, R1 and R2:

\$P=\dfrac{E^2}{R}  =\dfrac{5V^2}{100\Omega}=250mW\$

So balanced or not, you can't really *exceed* the maximum power ratings.

Comment: sorry... I've corrected my circuit..

Answer (score 1):

The bridge is balanced.

Current through R2 and R3 = 5V/(R2+R3) = 20 mA.

Power dissipated:

R2: (20mA)<sup>2</sup> · R2 = 40 mW
R3: (20mA)<sup>2</sup> · R3 = 60 mW

Check Total 5<sup>2</sup>/(R2+R3) = 100 mW

Current through R1 and R4 = 5V/(R1+R4) = 2 mA.

Power dissipated:

R2: (2mA)<sup>2</sup> · R1 = 4 mW
R3: (2mA)<sup>2</sup> · R4 = 6 mW

Check total: 5<sup>2</sup>/(R1+R4) = 10 mW

So all okay.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose each bridge resistor is capable of dissipating 250mW. Can the
>   bridge be left in the balanced state without exceeding the
>   power-dissipating capacity of the resistors

Ignoring the problems with your circuit, if all four resistors are 100 ohms then the total power dissipated in the complete bridge is 5x5/100 = 250 mW and therefore each resistor will dissipate 62.5 mW and be OK.

If these are strain gauges, then they are very unlikely to change their resistive values by more than 10% so, if all resistors were 10% low the total power would be 278 mW and each element would still be OK.

If, the bridge resistances can be any value then sure, any amount of power could be produced and the bridge burn.

If the excitation voltage was 10 volts then the total power would be 1 watt and this is becoming a problem.

Comment: sorry... I've corrected my circuit..

Comment: @Junu my answer is unaffected by your amendment (luckily)